# Calling an particular portion of an JSP into another JSP

Tags: java, jsp

I have two JSP

```
------------------------------------
first.jsp

    .....
    <jsp:include page="second.jsp"/>
    ....

 <div id='anotherId' >
   how to include that secound.jsp 's div tag
 </div

-------------------------------------
second.jsp
....

   <div id='abc'>

</div>

------------------------------------------
```

The reason why am doing like this means I have lot of conditions checking in my JSP i don't want to club all those in to a single JSP so I split that into small divs and I want to access that from my JSP. Just only to have clean code

Help me to sort this.

Comment: Down voter can you please give me the reason so that i will improve my question. Without reason i cant post better.

Answer (score 0):

You need [custom tags](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnalj.html) inside JSP's and reuse them. [here is an example](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_custom_tags.htm)

Comment: Could you please elaborate your answer to get your idea better

Comment: I know custom tag but i dont know how that solves my prob here.